# How to manipulate user uploaded files in django without saving it?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm making an app which gets data from a csv file and generates a graph using it. All files contains the same structure. I've decided I'm not going to store the files, because of server prices. I'm going to use heroku for now to host this app. It's a Django app. I'm wondering how I could only open the file and extract the data of it using django. I've thought about creating a model and save each file content on it. How can I do this? Is this the best option for my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume you're using `Django 1.9` (if not, please update your question to reflect your version of Django).

First, using the HTML `<form>` tag, you'll want to include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as an attribute.

Assuming you'll name your `<input>` tag as `myFile` (`<form name="myFile">`), in your view, simply extract the file from `request.FILES`:

```
def my_file_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        myFile = request.FILES.get('myFile')
        # At this point, myFile is an instance of UploadedFile, see
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/files/uploads/ for details
```

Read up on [uploaded files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/files/uploads/#uploaded-files) in the Django documentation to see the caveats associated with this approach.

Comment: For me, `myFile = request.FILES.get('myFile')` returns a string with the file name. Also, `Assuming you'll name your <input> tag as myFile (<form name="myFile">)` is contradictory. You indicate the <input> has the name and give an example of the form having that name.