# JSON file upload in Django without saving

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-rest-framework, django-file-upload

I want to upload, process and discard a JSON file without saving it in a database.

views.py

```
parser_classes(['FileUploadParser'])
@api_view(['POST'])
def upload_file(request):
    file = request.FILES.get('file')
    # process the file
    return JsonResponse('status':'successful')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/upload_file/', views.upload_file),
]
```

I am setting the header as `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`

Then it is showing the error `"Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None"`

What is the correct way of uploading a JSON file in DRF ?

Python version : 3.6.9
Django version : 3.2.3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manipulate user uploaded files in django without saving it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975156/how-to-manipulate-user-uploaded-files-in-django-without-saving-it)

Comment: @Faboor This does not answer my question as my question is specific to JSON files.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after trial and error. Basically the header part should be `application/json` in case of a JSON file upload. The data of the file can be accessed through `request.data`.
The `request.FILES` would be empty in case of a JSON file.